# How to group , count, and unstack a pandas dataframe based on multiple columns values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame in which I stored my Win/Loss results of multiple models and multiple companies

| company | Model_1 | Winloss | Model_2 | Winloss2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | KNN | W | GPR | L |
| Company1 | KNN | L | PLS | W |
| Company1 | KNN | L | KRR | W |
| Company1 | KNN | L | XGB | W |
| Company1 | GPR | L | SGD | W |
| Company2 | GPR | L | PLS | W |
| Company2 | KRR | L | XGB | W |

I want to group by both company and models and count Win-loss for each model within same company  so that I can later unstack the result to and have the output to look like this:

| ('company', '') | ('DT', 'L') | ('DT', 'W') | ('GPR', 'L') | ('KNN', 'L') | ('KNN', 'W') | ('KRR', 'W') | ('PLS', 'W') | ('SGD', 'W') | ('SVR', 'L') | ('SVR', 'W') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | 3.0 | 2.0 | 5.0 | 3.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 |
| Company2 | 6.0 | 2.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 6.0 | 1.0 |
| Company3 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 |
| Company4 | 6.0 | 1.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 |
| Company5 | 7.0 | 1.0 | 5.0 | 0.0 | 1.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 0.0 | 2.0 |

The table above is a result of my follwoing code but the numbers results of counted values were not accurate  :

```
WLPerCompany = WinLoss.groupby(['company','Model_1','Winloss']) 
['Winloss'].count()
WinLossResults = pd.DataFrame(WLPerCompany)
WinLossResults.columns = [*WinLossResults.columns[:-1], 'counts']
WinLossResults= WinLossResults['counts'].unstack(level=['Model_1', 
'Winloss'])
WinLossResults= WinLossResults.fillna(0)
WinLossResults
```

Comment: share some code to make your example reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) for reshape first and then [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index().rename(columns={'Winloss':'Winloss1'}), 
                     stubnames=['Model_','Winloss'], 
                     i=['index','company'], 
                     j='tmp').reset_index()

df = pd.crosstab(df['company'], [df['Model_'], df['Winloss']])
print (df)
Model_   GPR KNN    KRR    PLS SGD XGB
Winloss    L   L  W   L  W   W   W   W
company                               
Company1   2   3  1   0  1   1   1   1
Company2   1   0  0   1  0   1   0   1
```